# Comparing States in Java

Tags: java, oop, comparison, state

In my project, we have to create a system where we create an object Facility and we have to run inspections and maintenance on it to check if it's working. We created a Facility object and then we created a state machine that changes the state of the Facility to resting, working, maintenance, or working.

Here is the SuperFacility class:

```
import java.util.Map;

public interface SuperFacility {
    public void setName(String name);
    public void setAddress(String address);
    public void setDescription(String description);
    public void setRefNumber(int refNumber);
    public void setCapacity(int capacity);
    public void setCost(double cost);
    public void setProblemRate(int problemRate);
    public String getName();
    public String getAddress();
    public String getDescription();
    public int getRefNumber();
    public int getCapacity();
    public double getCost();
    public int getProblemRate();
    public void oxygenator(boolean oxygenator);
    public void nuclearReactor(boolean nuclearReactor);
    public void innerAirlocks(boolean innerAirlocks);
    public void externalAirlocks(boolean externalAirlocks);
    public void comms(boolean comms);
    public void waterMaking(boolean waterMaking);
    public void startMachines();
    public Map getMap();
    public void getFacilityStatus();
    public void getFacilityStatus(Map<String, Boolean> map);
}
```

Here is the Facility class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Facility extends StateMachine implements SuperFacility {

    public String name, address, description;
    public int refNumber, capacity, problemRate;
    private double cost;
    private Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    private boolean[] machines = new boolean[6];
    private boolean oxygenator, innerAirlocks, externalAirlocks,
            comms, nuclearReactor, waterMaking;
    private final int numberOfMachines = 6; // Number of Machines inside Facility

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setRefNumber(int refNumber){
        this.refNumber = refNumber;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity){
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost){
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public void setProblemRate(int problemRate){
        this.problemRate = problemRate;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public int getRefNumber(){
        return refNumber;
    }

    public int getCapacity(){
        return capacity;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }

    public int getProblemRate(){
        return problemRate;
    }

    public void oxygenator(boolean oxygenator){
        this.oxygenator = oxygenator;
    }

    public void nuclearReactor(boolean nuclearReactor){
        this.nuclearReactor = nuclearReactor;
    }

    public void innerAirlocks(boolean innerAirlocks){
        this.innerAirlocks = innerAirlocks;
    }

    public void externalAirlocks(boolean externalAirlocks){
        this.externalAirlocks = externalAirlocks;
    }

    public void comms(boolean comms){
        this.comms = comms;
    }

    public void waterMaking(boolean waterMaking){
        this.waterMaking = waterMaking;
    }

    public boolean[] getMachines(){
        machines[0] = oxygenator;
        machines[1] = nuclearReactor;
        machines[2] = innerAirlocks;
        machines[3] = externalAirlocks;
        machines[4] = comms;
        machines[5] = waterMaking;
        return machines;
    }

    // Set machines to false
    public void breakMachines(){
        oxygenator(false);
        nuclearReactor(false);
        innerAirlocks(false);
        externalAirlocks(false);
        comms(false);
        waterMaking(false);

        map.clear();
        initializeMap(map);
    }

    public void startMachines(){
        // Set all of the booleans from this Facility to true;
        // This booleans are what we call "the machines from the Facility"
        oxygenator(true);
        nuclearReactor(true);
        innerAirlocks(true);
        externalAirlocks(true);
        comms(true);
        waterMaking(true);

        map.clear();
        initializeMap(map);
    }

    public void initializeMap(Map<String, Boolean> map){
        this.map.put("Oxygenator", oxygenator);
        this.map.put("Inner Airlocks", innerAirlocks);
        this.map.put("External Airlocks", externalAirlocks);
        this.map.put("Nuclear Reactor", nuclearReactor);
        this.map.put("Comms", comms);
        this.map.put("WaterMaking", waterMaking);
    }

    public Map<String, Boolean> getMap(){
        return map;
    }

    public void getFacilityStatus(){ // The status of the map in this object
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> i: map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(i.getKey() + ": " + i.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void getFacilityStatus(Map<String, Boolean> map){ // The status of any Facility map
        for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> i: map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(i.getKey() + ": " + i.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the StateMachine class:

```
 public class StateMachine {

    public State state = State.RESTING;

    enum State {
        WORKING, RESTING, MAINTENANCE, BROKEN
    }

    public State getFacilityState(){
        return state;
    }

    public void setStateWorking(Facility fac){
        fac.state = State.WORKING;
    }

    public void setStateResting(Facility fac){
        fac.state = State.RESTING;
    }

    public void setStateMaintenance(Facility fac){
        fac.state = State.MAINTENANCE;
    }

    public void setStateBroken(Facility fac) { fac.state = State.BROKEN;}

    public State getState(){
        return state;
    }
}
```

In my Inspection class, I have two methods that have to check the state of the Facility to see if it's working, but I am having trouble with my if statement:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Inspection {

    private Facility fac;

    public boolean isBroken(){

        if (fac.state == State.BROKEN)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void makeMaintenanceRequest(Control c){

        if (fac.state == State.BROKEN){
            c.scheduleMaintenance(fac);
        }
    }
```

I want the methods to be able to compare the current state of a Facility to the Broken state. How should I compare the states? I keep getting the "cannot find symbol" error for State.BROKEN

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images of text.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: And btw, your if statement seems ""ok"".

Comment: How do I compare the states?

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot understand very well what you're trying to do, I can tell you the `Inspection` class might already work as you'd like.

I see you commented out the constructor, why? It was okay to *inject* a `Facility` instance inside `Inspection`. However, you should accept a `StateMachine` instead.

```
public class Inspection {
   private final StateMachine stateMachine;

   public Inspection(final StateMachine stateMachine) {
      this.stateMachine = stateMachine;
   }

   ...
}
```

Then, inside your `Inspection#isBroken` method

```
public boolean isBroken() {
   return this.stateMachine.getFacilityState() == State.BROKEN; // "this" not necessary
}
```

As `Facility` *extends* `StateMachine`, it exposes a `getFacilityState()` method.
And because `Facility` *extends* `StateMachine`, `Inspection` is able to accept it.

```
final Facility facility = new Facility(...);
final Inspection inspection = new Inspection(facility);
final boolean isBroken = inspection.isBroken();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to replace State.BROKEN with StateMachine.State.BROKEN

public boolean isBroken(){

```
    if (fac.state == StateMachine.State.BROKEN)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```